# While using ag-grid pagination in server side row model with checkbox selection every time the selected box is unselected when new page is fetched

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid with angular
In that while using Server side row model and pagination and selecting the particular row and move to second page, it calls the backend api to get the data as soon as the data is loading all the selected checkbox from page 1 is getting unselected and therefore calling the onSelectionChanged event.

expectation should be while moving the second page 1st page selected data won't be lost

Comment: Hi I have same issue ! did u fix it?